# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'connect')

Tags: reactjs, mqtt

I use `mqqtjs` package in reactjs and get the error
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'connect')`
at this line of code:

```
const mqttClient = mqtt.connect('ws://broker.emqx.io:8084/mqtt', mqttOptions);
```

Here is all my code:

```
function S2(props) {
      //mqtt connect attribute and function
     
          const [client, setClient] = useState(null);

          useEffect(() => {
            const mqttOptions = {
            clientId: 'emqx_react_' + Math.random().toString(16).substring(2, 8),
            username: 'emqx_test',
            password: 'emqx_test',
            clean: true,
            reconnectPeriod: 1000, 
            connectTimeout: 30 * 1000, 
            };
        
            const mqttClient = mqtt.connect('ws://broker.emqx.io:8084/mqtt', mqttOptions);
        
            mqttClient.on('connect', () => {
              console.log('Component A connected to MQTT');
              mqttClient.subscribe('testtopic/react', { qos: 0 });
            });
        
            mqttClient.on('message', (topic, message) => {
              console.log(`Received message in Component A from topic ${topic}: ${message.toString()}`);
            });
        
            setClient(mqttClient);
        
            return () => {
              mqttClient.end();
            };
          }, []);
      
      return (
        <div>
                  
        </div>
            
      );
}

export default S2;
```

Can you show me why it doesn't work?

I have reinstalled mqtt package many time and it still does not work.
I want it to connect to mqtt and publish a message to the topic above.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, **reproducible**, example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Currently you are not showing how `mqtt` is imported (bundlers can sometimes lead to issues like this). I note that you have closed your issue on the [mqttjs github repo](https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js/issues/1669) so suspect you have found the solution yourself? (if so please add an answer; it may help others).

Answer (score 1):

You can import mqtt as below, it fixed my error

```
import * as mqtt from 'mqtt'
```

For more reference you can visit this https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js/issues/1669